# Black Screen when Booting Ubuntu on Asus Netbook

Tags: boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I tried installing Ubuntu on my netbook through a bootable USB a few days back. After installation I happened to use Ubuntu for quite some time and later shut down my netbook.

When I tried booting the netbook again, it just shows a black screen with a blinking cursor after the initial Asus screen. I tried opening BIOS by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> but it ain't coming either.

What should I do?

I pressed <kbd>F2</kbd> during the Asus screen and I'm pretty sure that <kbd>f2</kbd> is my bios button since I've used it before. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>l+<kbd>Del</kbd> during the black window with blinking cursor makes the netbook restart. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> ain't doing anything..

Comment: When are you pressing F2? When you first boot up (that is, when you see the ASUS logo)? That's when you should press it, to enter the BIOS. Once you see a black screen with a blinking cursor, an OS or bootloader has started. If you're pressing it at the right time, are you sure F2 is the key for your machine's BIOS setup? What's the exact model of your ASUS netbook? Can you to boot from a USB drive? When you see a blinking cursor, does Ctrl+Alt+F1 do anything? Ctrl+Alt+Del? [Alt+SysRq+REISUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reisub#Uses)? Please **edit your question** to provide this information.

Comment: I've replied....

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't go even to BIOS? Then something is wrong with hardware - I recommend to put it into computer service. Maybe motherboard is broken.